# Equivalent of zfill() in impala

Tags: sql, impala

I am selecting a string variable that represents a number in Impala. The thing is that I want all of them to have the same number of characters (2).

Current request :

```
select number from base.table
```

Result :

```
1
12
13
6
7
24
```

What I want :

```
01
12
13
06
07
24
```

There is a function called `zfill()` in python that does this, and I was wondering if there is an equivalent in Impala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`lpad`](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html) function.

```
select lpad(num,2,'0')
from tbl
```